# sass media queries with min and max width and an object of sizes

Tags: sass

I'm a beginner to sass (10 minutes of experience)

i've built a basic grid `_grid.scss`

the contents of this file are as follows:

```
$gutter  : 0 15px;
$columns : 12;
$sizes: (
  sm: 0,
  md: 640px,
  lg: 1024px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1440px,
);

.container{
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: $gutter;
}
.container.fluid{
    max-width:none;
}

.row:before, 
.row:after {
    content:' ';
    display: table ;
     clear:both;
}

.col{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: $gutter;
}

.col:after{
    content:'.';
    visibility: hidden;
}

@each $size,$breakpoint in $sizes{

    @media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint) {

        @for $i from 1 through $columns{

            .col.#{$size}-#{$i}{
                width: percentage($i/$columns);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

it outputs a nice grid as expected based on the number of `$columns`.

what i would like to do now is change the media query to use both min width and max width, and im having trouble figuring out how i can change the size object to store a min width and max width, then iterate that.

my basic idea would be to do something like:

```
$sm : 0px 639px;
$md : 640px 1023px;
$lg : 1024px 1199px;
$xl : 1200px 1439px;
$xxl: 1440px 4000px;

$sizes: (
  sm: $sm,
  md: $md,
  lg: $lg,
  xl: $xl,
  xxl: $xxl,
);
```

but if i did this, i would have no idea how to select the variables in the `$breakpoint` variable of the each loop. would i just do `$breakpoint[0]` for the min width and `$breakpoint[1]` for the max width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question. **to select an index from a list, use the `nth` function, which has a signature like so:

`nth($list,$index)` fwiw, the index is 1 based (weird).

the only changes i had to make were to change `$sizes` object like so:

```
$sm : 0px , 639px;
$md : 640px, 1023px;
$lg : 1024px, 1199px;
$xl : 1200px, 1439px;
$xxl: 1440px, 4000px;

$sizes: (
  sm: $sm,
  md: $md,
  lg: $lg,
  xl: $xl,
  xxl: $xxl,
);
```

and the media query to so:

```
@media screen and (min-width: nth($breakpoint,1)) and (max-width: nth($breakpoint,2))
```

presto, works like a charm. hopefully someone else finds this useful.